# Fragment instances are kept in viewPager2 when host fragment removed

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2, fragment-lifecycle, fragmentstateadapter

Have one activity app, where I have HomeFragment from which I open HostFragment, and HostFragment has ViewPager2 with 3 fragment items TabFragment1, TabFragment2 and TabFragment3.

When I open the HostFragment, and then go back, my tabFragments' instances are not removed. Below is the logs from lifecycles

> navController.navigate(directionToHostFragment)

1. HostFragment OnStart HostFragment{c37542c}
2. TabFragment1 OnStart TabFragment1 {f41b08}

> navController.popBackStack()

3. HostFragment OnPause HostFragment{c37542c}
4. HostFragment OnStop{c37542c}
5. HostFragment OnDestroy {c37542c}

> navController.navigate(directionToHostFragment)
> Blockquote

6. HostFragment OnStart{2670c03}
7. TabFragment1 OnStart{f45b87d}

> navController.popBackStack()

8. HostFragment OnPause{2670c03}
9. HostFragment OnStop{2670c03}
10. HostFragment onDestroy{2670c03}

From ids you can see that there is a new TabFragment1 instance and old one haven't destroyed(I have logs in onPause(), onStop() etc.).

Some code snippets:
Adapter for viewPager2 I used -

```
class LessonTabsAdapter(fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity, val pages: List<BaseFragment>) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {
    override fun getItemCount() = pages.size
    override fun createFragment(position: Int) = pages[position]
}
```

Some part from TabFragment1

```
class TabFragment1 : BaseFragment(R.layout.fragment_tab_1) {
    private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayerClass? = null
    private lateinit var player: SimpleExoPlayer

    private val viewModel by sharedViewModel<SomeViewModel>()
    private val binding by viewDataBinding(FragmentTab1Binding::bind)
    //Overriden onViewCreated(..) and some private methods 
}
```

So any hints how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the HostFragment the `ViewPager2` creates a fragment in the lifecycle provided. In this case you are passing activity as the parameter so, it is creating the fragments in `Activity's` lifecycle. You can check the same by printing the activity?.supportFragmentManager?.fragments list. If you want to couple the `ViewPager2`'s childs with `HostFRagment`, you need to pass the fragments instance to the `FragmentStateAdapter`. Check the function `2` that I have added. The best way to implement the `ViewPager2` is by using function `3`.

```java
1..
public FragmentStateAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
  this(fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragmentActivity.getLifecycle());
}

2.//
public FragmentStateAdapter(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
  this(fragment.getChildFragmentManager(), fragment.getLifecycle());
}

3.//
public FragmentStateAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
   mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
   mLifecycle = lifecycle;
   super.setHasStableIds(true);
}
```

Comment: Don't know how I missed that part. That worked for me. Thank you @Chhatrasal Singh Bundela.